# Custom filter option for ‘does not contain a date’

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2003

I have an Excel worksheet that I want to filter for entries that do not contain a date such as `mm/dd/yy`. I currently do it by custom filter “the year not equal to 2012 or 2013”. But in this case I have a wider range of dates.

Is there a way I can filter the sheet by “cell does not contain a date”?

I am using Office Excel 2003 with Windows XP.

Comment: Do you know/want to use VBA? Cause that has an `isdate()` function.

Comment: are the other values text or numbers? If numbers, any specific range?

Comment: @nutsch, the range is from 1/1/1900 to now. (Basically it is like date of birth of the member).

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a cell (example A1) formatted as a date with:

```
=LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="D"
```

(returns TRUE) then might use that FALSE for filtering.